# How to preview xml drawable?

Tags: android, xml-drawable

I'm working on pretty complex xml drawable and i was wondering if there is any tool/plugins which allow me to preview my drawable ?

I'm looking for something similar to the "Graphical layout" tab available for layout.

For example if i have something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:left="0dp" android:right="0dp"> 
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#2B2B2B"
                android:endColor="#000000" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="1sp" android:bottom="26sp" > 
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#10ffffff"/>
    </shape>

    </item>
</layer-list>
```

How can i preview the shape and gradient ?
And i'm probably dreaming , but is there any graphical tools to build a drawable ?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

In Android Studio do this: View -> Tool Windows -> Preview

Comment: Would it be obvious for Android users to know which tool you are referring to?

Comment: @grunk I recommend to accept this answer as correct.

Answer (score 9):

Android Studio has support for this starting with version 0.3.2: http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio032released

Answer (score 7):

Click on PREVIEW on the right side of the window.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In Eclipse
Create new layout with root LinearLayout.
Open Outline view.
In properties table find View.Background.
Press button ...
Now you can chose Color and Drawable resources and there is small preview.

[image: Preview in Eclipse]

Answer (score 4):

Android Studio offers a nice plugin named

```
"Vector Drawable Thumbnails"
```

This adds a nice overview over all vector drawables in your project.
Just have a look at the side bar and open the view. You will get a thumbnail table of them.

[image: Vector Drawable Thumbnails]

Answer (score 3):

Android Studio 2X

1. View -> Tool Windows -> Preview
2. Or click on **Preview** on the right side

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility:

Just create a new layout "test", goto graphical layout, create a button inside (or any view), and assign the drawable to the button's background. The drawable is rendered (its normal state).

Answer (score 1):

One way to preview the resources is by using the Resource Manager in Android Studio. It's visible as a separate tab:

[image: PrintScreen]

Answer (score 1):

The Preview options mentioned in previous answers aren't there in Android Studio 4.0. Look for this segmented control in the top-right of the editor tab instead.

[image: Android Studio 4.0.1 showing code/split/design control]

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to preview selector you can find tabs with states on Preview Panel
[image]

Comment: how do you get this states tabs? currently they is no visible way of getting those

Comment: 4 years later, running Android Studio Giraffe 2022.3.1 and I can't find where to turn on this states bar either.